# MFC program compiled with VS 2012 won't start in Windows Server 2003

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

We have an application built with VS2008 and migrated to vs2012, everything works except with Windows Server 2003 and probably in XP as well.

I have changed the toolset to use V110_xp for the exe app and all its dependencies, and still not working.

application doesn't start with no errors, no dmp files, nothing in event viewer.

I tried remote debugger but I could not see the process either because it doesn't come up in the process list so I cannot attach anything.

I've also placed a message box in the constructor of the main form class to block the thread and eventually attach to the process using a remote debugger but I did not get to the message box either!

Can anyone help?

Comment: did you install the Visual C++ Redistributable Package (vcredist_x64.exe and/or vcredist_x86.exe)? Try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if a required dll is missing.

Comment: I did run dependecy walker, and it didn't show me anything is missing. But do I need to install VC++ redist package?

Comment: If nothing is missing, you don't need to install it. It depends on your compiler settings whether you need it or not.

Comment: if you got a dependency on the VC runtime (e.g. using operator new somewhere), you got to install it as part of your setup program

Comment: Just a guess, maybe security setting. You can try run the program as Administrator, and see if that works.

Comment: program is installed under administrator role based user.

Comment: I've also tried to install vc++ redistributable package and still nothing.

Comment: Have you looked in Event Viewer?

Comment: yes I did look in the event viewer. Nothing!!!